# the error of Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation

Tags: tensorflow

When running a [tensorflow program](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet/blob/master/tf_unet/unet.py), I keep having the following error messages, the major part of which is something like `TypeError: Fetch argument[....]has invalid type <class 'list'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.)`  The related code segment that directly causes this error is `_, loss, lr, gradients = sess.run((self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node, self.net.gradients_node),                                                 feed_dict={self.net.x: batch_x,self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y,pred_shape), self.net.keep_prob: dropout})`

I just feel confused about the reason to cause this error message because it can be run successfully by the author as shown in the github post.

The total error messages is as follows:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/develop/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 480, in _process_fetches
    allow_operation=True)
  File "/develop/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2301, in as_graph_element
    % (type(obj).**name**, types_str))
TypeError: Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in 
    path = trainer.train(generator, "./unet_trained", training_iters=20, epochs=100, display_step=2)
  File "/home/user/test/u-net/ver3/unet.py", line 364, in train
    self.net.keep_prob: dropout})
  File "/develop/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/develop/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 523, in _run
    processed_fetches = self._process_fetches(fetches)
  File "/develop/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 493, in _process_fetches
    % (subfetch, fetch, type(subfetch), str(e)))
TypeError: Fetch argument [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ] of [, , , , , , , , , , <                                                                                                                 :0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, , , , , , , , ] has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Tensorflow version [r0.9](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) or a previous version, Session.run didn't accept arbitrarily nested list or tuple in the fetches argument. So self.net.gradients_node (which is a list of tensor) in the tuple cause your TypeError. This code should work in Tensorflow [r0.10](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session).
If you prefer stay at r0.9, modify the line :

```
_, loss, lr, gradients = sess.run((self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node, self.net.gradients_node), feed_dict={self.net.x: batch_x,self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y,pred_shape), self.net.keep_prob: dropout})
```

to

```
list_of_outputs = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node]+ self.net.gradients_node, feed_dict={self.net.x: batch_x,self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y,pred_shape), self.net.keep_prob: dropout})
loss = list_of_outputs[1]
lr = list_of_outputs[2]
gradients = list_of_outputs[2:]
```

or (with Python 3.*)

```
_,loss,lr,*gradients = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node]+ self.net.gradients_node, feed_dict={self.net.x: batch_x,self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y,pred_shape), self.net.keep_prob: dropout})
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try. Our current version is 0.8.0.

Comment: Hi Corentin, excuse me for replying late, due to a vacation. I tried as you suggested, looks like it works. However, it gives another error message for the revised one.  _,loss,lr,gradients = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node]+self.net.gradients_node,feed_dict={self.net.x: batch_x,self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y, pred_shape),self.net.keep_prob: dropout})
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Comment: No problem user288609 ;). Ok for the ValueError, I forgot something : the Session.run function return a list with the same size of fetches, so 3+len(self.net.gradients_node) in your case. The first 3 values are None, the loss and the learning rate. And the end of the list are all gradients of the model. So I modified my answer to unpack this variables manually.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a very neat answer. Previously, I googled a lot, and I modified the code this way. _,loss,lr,*gradients = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node]+self.net.gradients_node,feed_dict={‌​self.net.x: batch_x,self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y, pred_shape),self.net.keep_prob: dropout})      In specific, I add * before gradients. Looks like it works, but frankly speaking, I am not quite sure i really understand why. My guess is that gradients means a lot of nested tuples without knowing the exact number of them. I just use * to capture them.

Comment: Great, I didn't know this notation. But it seems to work only with python 3. For the gradients shape, it's a list  see tf.gradients specs.